# My solution for diameter of binary tree problem gives wrong result

Tags: tree

I am doing LeetCode problem [543. Diameter of Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, return *the length of the **diameter** of the tree.*
>
> The **diameter** of a binary tree is the **length** of the longest path between any two nodes in a tree. This path may or may not pass through the `root`.
>
> The **length** of a path between two nodes is represented by the number of edges between them.

I thought that I solved the problem, but my code doesn't work for this test case. Could you advise me what I am missing?

#### Input:

```
[4,-7,-3,null,null,-9,-3,9,-7,-4,null,6,null,-6,-6,null,null,0,6,5,null,9,null,null,-1,-4,null,null,null,-2]
```

#### Expected output:

```
8
```

My code outputs 7

#### My Code

```py
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        def dfs(node:TreeNode, depth:int):
            if not node:
                return depth
            depth += 1
            left_depth = dfs(node.left, depth)
            right_depth = dfs(node.right, depth)
            return max(left_depth, right_depth)

        l = dfs(root.left, 0)
        r = dfs(root.right, 0)
        return l + r
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code assumes that the longest path always runs through the root. However the code challenge already includes a hint about this:

> ...This path may or may not pass through the `root`

The graph represented by:

```
[4,-7,-3,null,null,-9,-3,9,-7,-4,null,6,null,-6,-6,null,null,0,6,5,null,9,null,null,-1,-4,null,null,null,-2]
```

is:

```
         ____ 4 ___
        /          \
      -7       ____-3___
              /         \
         ___-9___       -3
        /        \      /
       9         -7   -4
      /         /  \
   __6__      -6   -6
  /     \     /    /
 0       6   5    9
  \     /        /
  -1  -4       -2
```

Now see that the path between -1 and -2 has 8 edges, while the longest path through the root only has 7 (-1 to -7).

So you'll have to revise your algorithm to look at possibilities where the "highest" node in the longest path is not the root.

Hint 1:

> Not only the heights of the two subtrees play a role, but the diameters of the two subtrees. These are different metrics.

Hint 2:

> When the length of the longest path through a node is determined by the heights of its two subtrees, it still needs to be compared with the diameters that were calculated for the two subtrees. Which ever is greater should be the diameter of the current node.

Spoiler implementation:

> `class Solution:
>     def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
>         if not root:
>             return -1
>         leftDia = self.diameterOfBinaryTree(root.left)
>         rightDia = self.diameterOfBinaryTree(root.right)
>         leftHeight = root.left.val if root.left else -1
>         rightHeight = root.right.val if root.right else -1
>         # (ab)use the node's value for storing its height.
>         root.val = 1 + max(leftHeight, rightHeight)
>         return max(leftDia, rightDia, 2 + leftHeight + rightHeight)`